# Cannot add CSRF token to XMLhttpRequest for Django POST request

Tags: javascript, django, post, xmlhttprequest, csrf

CSRF token is not being added to the header of the XMLhttpRequest.

To make sure all the other code works, I've tried using a GET request to the server and everything works as it should. However when I add the CSRF token to the header the code stops running when adding the header.

```
// [PROBLEM CODE]
// Initialize new request
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
const currency = document.querySelector('#currency').value;

request.setRequestHeader({'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken}); // [<---HERE]
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"); // [<---HERE]

request.open('POST', '/convert');


// [THIS WORKS]
// Initialize new request
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
const currency = document.querySelector('#currency').value;
request.open('GET', '/convert');
request.send();
```

When I take out the two problem lines of code, setRequestHeader and make a POST request. The error message I get is "Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /convert"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't pass `setRequestHeader` an object, but a `header` and a `value`. See docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader).

From [reading this](http://musings.tinbrain.net/blog/2015/aug/28/vanilla-js-meets-djangos-csrf/), I believe it should be `'X-CSRFToken'`.

Also, before setting the request header you need to set the request to open.

If you update it to the following it should work.

```
request.open('POST', '/convert');
request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken); 
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"); 
request.send();
```

Comment: are you seeing an error, or it's just not being passed over?

Comment: not being passed over, I added a javascript alert, and the code does not get past those two lines of code.

Comment: @ArthurChoate see updated answer. Try set the request to `open` first. Seems as if the article is wrong, as it doesn't open the state first.  It works here, albeit with an error as `/convert` doesn't exist obviously - https://jsfiddle.net/L1trg3ko/

Comment: great stuff @ArthurChoate

Comment: For csrftoken, add `{% csrf_token %}` above the script and add `const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;` before the second line in the above answer. I'm 99% certain that server-side, the data sent via request.send will be found only in request.body.

Answer (score 0):

```
Your Templates such as view.html:
...
<p>{% csrf_token %}<button onclick="your_event(this)">Name_button</button></p>
...

Your js:

function your_event(self) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    csrftoken=self.parentElement.firstChild.value
    xhr.open('POST', 'your_site', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");   
    xhr.send();
      
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        your_function

    }
    something_else
    }
```

Comment: Please consider adding further explanation to the answer to supplement the code provided.